# Alternative to :last selector to select the correct div

Tags: jquery

I have several divs that are generated dynamically after a file is uploaded. Each file upload creates a div in this format:

```
<div id="uploadifive-fileupload-queue" class="uploadifive-queue">
    <div class="uploadifive-queue-item complete" id="uploadifive-fileupload-file-0">

        <div id="inputs">

            some text

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every item uploaded increments the id of the uploadifive-queue-item class to uploadifive-fileupload-file-0, uploadifive-fileupload-file-1, uploadifive-fileupload-file-2, etc.

What I am trying to do is add a class to `#inputs`, but only the one just created.

I can do it using :last when I am only uploading one at a time, but if I select multiple at the same time, it only applies to the very last div in that group.

What I am looking for is like a $(this) or a way to target that unique div.

```
  $('#fileupload').uploadifive({
                'buttonClass'  : 'btn btn-primary',
                'buttonText'   : 'Select Thumbnail',
                'dnd' : false,
                'fileSizeLimit' : 1000,
                'method' : 'post',
                'simUploadLimit' : 1,
                'uploadScript' : './upload/',
                'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) {
                    $("#uploadifive-fileupload-queue .uploadifive-queue-item:last").find('#inputs').addClass('alert-error');
                }

            });
```

`#fileupload` is just the name of the form, here's the HTML:

```
<form id="fileupload">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
</form>
```

The divs are added directly underneath and are inside the same container.

How can I select the correct div?

Comment: Side note: `id` attributes must always be unique, including your `id="inputs"`

Comment: Side comment: you should not be creating multiple DIVs with id="anything".  IDs are (by definition) unique identifiers of elements.  If you duplicate them, browsers will be generous and allow it, but you may run in to problems later on because of it.

Comment: In any case, I'm confused: `$(this)` should work from inside any jQuery event handler (unless it's been proxied or something).

Comment: The context changes within the success callback; you can just cache the element before by doing `var self=this;` then using `self` later in your method instead.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate ids are part of the problem, try changing them to class names or unique values.

The other part is that this:

```
$("#uploadifive-fileupload-queue .uploadifive-queue-item:last")
```

...selects the last (and only) `.uploadifive-queue-item` in the **first**, unique, `#uploadifive-fileupload-queue` element: http://jsfiddle.net/aLRhL/2/

So the dupe ids and incorrect selectors are the issue. Try this instead, change `id="inputs"` to `class="inputs"` and use:

```
$(".uploadifive-queue:last .inputs").addClass('alert-error');
```

...and make sure to fix the rest of those duplicate ids.

Even with the dupe ids, it [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/aLRhL/1/) if you have the correct selector, but don't rely on it.